# Tits Alternative for Hyperbolic Groups: A Reference Request.

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, geometric-group-theory, combinatorial-group-theory

### Details:

> **Definition:** A class $\mathcal{G}$ of groups satisfies the *Tits alternative* if for any $G$ in $\mathcal{G}$ either $G$ has a free, non-abelian subgroup or $G$ has a solvable subgroup of finite index.

### The Request:

> I need a reference, please, for the theorem that [hyperbolic groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_group) satisfy the Tits Alternative.

(Please see the Wikipedia article linked to above for a definition of hyperbolic groups.)

### Thoughts:

My guess is that it's

> Gromov, Mikhail (1987). "Hyperbolic Groups". In Gersten, S.M. (ed.). *Essays in Group Theory.* Mathematical Sciences Research Institute Publications, vol 8. New York, NY: Springer. **pp.** 75–263.

It is from the hyperbolic groups Wikipedia page. I recognise the name from his other work (I think) in geometric group theory.

However, the paper is behind a paywall.

I require the reference for my research.

Please help :)

Comment: You can find Gromov's paper on his website, or maybe use a library

Comment: It's more of a book than a paper at nearly 200 pages long, @PaulPlummer! But thank you.

Comment: Gromov's book is full of ideas, but short on proofs. Its not the best place to go for an introduction to the subject...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Tits alternative for hyperbolic groups follows from the fact that a hyperbolic group either contains a cyclic subgroup of finite index (so called "elementary hyperbolic groups") or contains a free subgroup of rank two.

Note that you can find a pdf of Gromov's essay on his website [here](https://www.ihes.fr/~gromov/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/657.pdf).

The relevant result is as follows. This is a simplified version of Theorem 5.3.E of Gromov's essay (p68 of the pdf, p142 of text). A more modern citation is Proposition III.$\Gamma$.3.20 of Bridson and Haefliger, *Metric spaces of non-positive curvature*.

**Theorem.** Let $\Gamma$ be a hyperbolic group, and let $g, h\in\Gamma$ be elements of infinite order such that $\langle g, h\rangle$ is non-cyclic. Then there exists some $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $\langle g^n, h^n\rangle$ is free of rank two.

Note that in order to apply the above theorem to the Tits alternative you need to prove that if $\Gamma$ is not virtually-cyclic then there exist two elements of infinite order $g, h\in\Gamma$ such that $\langle g, h\rangle$ is non-cyclic (this is clear if $\Gamma$ is torsion-free, while an afternoon with Gromov's essay or Bridson-Haefliger should clear up the "with torsion" case). However, it is extremely well-known that non-elementary hyperbolic groups contain non-abelian free subgroups so if you are just after something to cite then citing the above references would be sufficient.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping-pong_lemma#Word-hyperbolic_group_example) has an elegant proof of the above theorem for torsion-free hyperbolic groups, using Ping-Pong and the action of $\Gamma$ on the boundary $\partial\Gamma$. This seems to be 8.2.E of Gromov's essay (p138/212), but Gromov is rather terse...

Comment: Is the subtlety of the with torsion case you are referring to is "infinite hyperbolic groups are not torsion"?

Comment: @PaulPlummer Basically, yes.

Answer (score 4):

If you read French: Theorem 37, p. 157 in the book by Ghys and de la Harpe "Hyperbolic groups after Gromov".

Comment: I'm afraid I can't read French. Thank you nonetheless. I'm not sure what to do about this situation.

Comment: @Shaun: There are other references... But also, learn to read mathematical French.

Comment: @Shaun: Although I do not know if you are a native English speaker who knows mathematical English, I'll just say that if you are, and if you have never never studied French, here is how you learn to read mathematical French: pick up an ordinary French dictionary, pick up the paper in mathematical French that you wish to read, and go from there.