# Whether a group containing a free group is also a free group

Tags: group-theory, free-groups, finitely-generated, combinatorial-group-theory

Suppose $G$ is a group generated by two elements $s,t$.

Suppose $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ such that $H= \langle s^k,t^k \rangle$ is a free group where $k$ is some integer not equal to $1$.

Does it imply that $G$ is also a free group?

Note: I know there are examples of non free group with a free subgroup. But in those examples, the subgroup had different generators.
But I want to know about this particular case where the generators of the subgroup has some power of the generators of the mother group.

Comment: This is obviously untrue if you're asking if $H$ is free of arbitrary rank, set $G=\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/k$, then $H$ is free of rank $1$ for $s = (1,0)$, $t = (0,1)$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, this is not true.

For an extreme class of counter-examples, consider [*hyperbolic*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_group) groups, which are an extremely common* class of groups. If $G$ is a hyperbolic group then for all $g,h\in G$ there exists an integer $k\geq1$ such that $\langle g^k, h^k\rangle$ is free. So every non-free two-generated hyperbolic group gives you a counter-example. Often the promised free subgroup is free of rank two. Concrete examples include:
\begin{align}
\langle a, b\mid abab^2ab^3\cdots ab^n\rangle&\quad\forall\:n\gg1&(1)\\
\langle a, b\mid [a, b]^n\rangle &\quad \forall\:n>1&(2)\\
\langle a, b\mid a^n, [a, b]\rangle&\quad\forall\:n>0&(3)\\
\langle a, b\mid a^p, b^q, (ab)^r\rangle&\quad\forall\:\frac1p+\frac1q+\frac1r<1&(4)
\end{align}
In (1) and (2) there exists some $k$ such that $\langle a^k, b^k\rangle\cong F_2$. This is the "generic" case, as it happens if both generators have infinite order and don't commute (and a generic group is in fact "non-elementary" torsion-free hyperbolic). Note that the group in (2) is not torsion-free, although the generators have infinite order.

The result still holds for generators of finite order, it just won't be the free group of rank $2$ that you get. In (3), $\langle a^n, b^n\rangle\cong\mathbb{Z}$ which is the free group of rank $1$. In (4), $\langle a^{pq}, b^{pq}\rangle$ is trivial, which is free of rank $0$.

To save myself duplicating work: references to proofs are [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3388055/10513). Theorem 5.3.E of Gromov's "Essay" is actually a more powerful result, covering multiple generators.

---

*Both in the sense that they crop up everywhere, and that they are ["generic"](http://www.yann-ollivier.org/rech/publs/randomgroups.pdf) within the class of finitely presented groups.

Comment: Can you provide a link of the proof of the existence of such k for hyperbolic groups?

Comment: Presumably you need to require at least that$g$ and $h$ don't commute?

Comment: @Newrion It is one of the standard results for hyperbolic groups, so is in almost every text covering them. I've added a link to a previous answer of mine which points to some proofs ([this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping-pong_lemma#Word-hyperbolic_group_example) is elegant, if you have the prior knowledge).

Comment: @Troposphere No, and I've added in an example which includes this case. Note that in hyperbolic groups, if $g,h$ commute then they have a common power, so the free group $\langle g^k, h^k\rangle$ will be either infinite cyclic or trivial.

Comment: @user1729: Is it then a typo when the original statement promises that "$\langle g^k,h^k\rangle$ is free _of rank two_"? That seemed to exclude being infinite cyclic or trivial.

Comment: @Troposphere Yes, that's a typo! Fixed it now. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, then it make more sense. I take it then when you say "If the group is torsion-free and not infinite cyclic then the promised free subgroup is free of rank two," you have left the scope of "for all $g,h\in G$" -- that tripped me up for several minutes.

Comment: @Troposphere Sorry, you're right. I was only meaning the generators there. I've corrected it now.